# PHP/SQL "Duplicate column name" error when adding columns

Tags: php, sql

I'm fairly new to this and mostly self taught, so please be gentle. :)

I'm making a survey template that generates a table for a survey that has as many columns as there are attributes in the survey (plus key).

First of all I'm creating a one column table "Concepts" that only has my keys, which is working fine. Then I'm doing the following but I keep getting this error: **Duplicate column name 'Attr3'**. My array of attributes only has the values Attr1, Attr2, Attr3 (I'm sure plus it shows as I echo it at each iteration: **Attr1Attr2Attr3Error adding columns: Duplicate column name 'Attr3'**). The same thing happens with a foreach() loop and with mysqli_multi_query() inside or outside the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
.
.
.

$i = 0;

for ($k=0; $k < sizeof($attributes); $k++) 
{        
  $a = mysql_real_escape_string($attributes[$k]); 
  echo "$a";
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE Concepts ADD $a VARCHAR(64)";
  $i = $k;      
}

mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql); 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
  echo "<br>" . $i . " columns added successfully";
} 
else 
{
  echo "Error adding columns: " . $conn->error;
}
echo"<br>";
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: @Matt is there a reason why your altering a table column from a PHP script? and not in SQL or some type of GUI (phpMyAdmin, SequelPro)

Comment: You are attempting to add a column too a database when there is a column with the same name already defined for that table.

Comment: That's because I'd like one user to be able to create a survey for another user as easily as possible and I figured this is the way.

Comment: and you probably want to run your update statement INSIDE the loop.

Comment: @Orangepill: The table has only one column, "keys", before above code is being executed. Also, if I have the for loop stop at "(sizeof($attributes) -1)", I get the same error, just with "Attr2" instead of "Attr3" being the duplicate column .

Comment: put the update statement inside the loop, same error

Comment: This isn't the way doing it -> this way you will probably need a new table for each new survey, not to mention all the other issues this will quickly become overwhelming to maintain. You can / should do basically 1 of 2 things store your survey as Json or some other serialized data in a single column/field, or make a key value store for it, what that is is a table with 3-4 columns  user_id, field_name, field_value, survey_id, something like that.

Comment: @MKramer - what if I make a survey and I want a column named keys?  The method you chose to do it should be based of how you plan to search this data, same for the survey answers.  Do you plan to let the person making the survey modify it at a later time, say after someone has taken a survey, that can really complicate things.

Comment: @MKramer - have you looked for an open source survey framework that is already built, here is one https://manual.limesurvey.org/Installation I am sure there are more.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! There will be no more than, say, 5 active surveys at the same time and no more than 3-5 participants in each. It is about how people evaluate pieces of audio (my html front end has an audio player embedded for each key). Let's say there are 10 pieces and 5 attributes. If someone deems that "attribute 3" applies to "piece 5", I want my code to add "1" to that cell in the table.

Comment: I'm happy to consider alternative solutions, but I still can't get my head around why it keeps trying to duplicatie the last column..